# Set InnerClass broadcastreceiver to android action

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

This is what I am using right now:

in the onCreate method:

```
registerReceiver(bootup, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"));
```

the bootup receiver:

```
BroadcastReceiver bootup = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("test", "received");
    }
};
```

These are both in the MainActivity class of my app. What I want is for the bootup receiver to be called when the bootup of the phone is complete. I need it in the MainActivity class because I need to access a few things from it.

How would I set this? My current solution does not work.

EDIT: The posted solution seems as though it will work for my purpose, and this is what has been suggested by other threads. However, when I put a log statement in the receiver that it ties to, nothing appears in the console. Is this because the application is not running? I have also tried sending a notification with notificationmanager

EDIT 2: I took advice and switched to a broadcastreceiver in a another class for detecting the reboot. It works by simply changing the name attribute on the manifest file. This being the reason why I cant use an inner class receiver doesn't really make any sense compared to what I have seen on other questions. Can someone explain why I can't point the receiver to the inner class one and why I have to use a separate class?

Comment: This is not possible at all. Your activity is not instanciated at boot time, you can't access it there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Receiver:

```
public class BootupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String ACTION_BOOT = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (ACTION_BOOT.equals(intent.getAction()))
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.bootup_receiver, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And receiver and uses-permission in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver android:name="com.example.restarttest.BootupReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I have this receiver in the MainActivity class and set everything as you suggested. I put a log statement to the console to notify me when the phone restarts, but it is not showing up. the name of the receiver in the manifest file is eli.me.jitteralarm.MainActivity$BootupReceiver, which may be the issue, but I don't think so.

Comment: Try put BootupReceiver  in a single file.

Comment: I would, but it needs to access some methods from the main activity class.

Comment: You can't access methods from main activity.Or your can move method to Receiver.